# MongoDB: List the usernames and the amount of replies they received

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have a collection set up in mongoDB with sample comments made by users from a made up social media platform, in this form:

```
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("5aa58936c4214f42f4c666b8"),
     "id" : "85",
     "user_name": "Alex4Ever",
     "text" : "This is a comment",
     "in_reply_to_user_name": "SamLad"
},
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("5aa58935c4214f42f4c66608"),
     "id" : "86",
     "user_name": "SamLad",
     "text" : "I am inevitable",
     "in_reply_to_user_name": null
},
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("5aa588e4c4214f42f4c63caa"),
     "id" : "87",
     "user_name": "HewwoKitty",
     "text" : "What is grief, if not love persevering?",
     "in_reply_to_user_name": "Alex4Ever"
} //There are more, but for testing purposes, I only use these 3 for now.
```

I have to come up with a query in MongoDB to list all the users in the file along with the amount of replies they received. So in the above sample bit of file, the output should be like:

```
"_id": "Alex4Ever", "replyCount" : 1,  //HewwoKitty replied to Alex4Ever
"_id": "SamLad", "replyCount" : 1,     //Alex4Ever replied to SamLad
"_id": "HewwoKitty", "replyCount" : 0, //No one replied to HewwoKitty
```

My attempt at doing this:

```
db.comments.aggregate([
                      {$match:{"in_reply_to_user_name":{"$exists":true, "$ne":null}}},
                      {$group: { _id: "$in_reply_to_user_name", replyCount:{$sum: 1}}}, 
                      {$sort:{replyCount: -1}}
                     ]).pretty()
```

However, I only get the non-zero values, i.e. I do not get `HewwoKitty` with a `replyCount` of `0`. Is there any way to print all 3 lines, including the lines with 0 replies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/JA9YasEYuVV

Use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and create self join to get all replies for a user and use [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) to get the count of replies, after that [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) them on user_name.

Extract the replyCount, take [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) value from the group

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "in_reply_to_user_name": { "$exists": true }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "user_name",
      "foreignField": "in_reply_to_user_name",
      "as": "replies"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "user_name": 1,
      "replyCount": { "$size": "$replies" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$user_name",
      "replyCount": {  "$first": "$replyCount" }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. :)